# New Auth Dialog give proxy email address

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

I start using the new Auth Dialog and I set it to ask for the users email permission, the problem is that I get the user proxy email address (with facebook servers). How can I solve this? I need the user original email.

I'm using JS sdk and FQL to retrive user email, but recieveing proxy email:

```
 FB.api(
          {
              method: 'fql.query',
              query: 'SELECT name, email FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
          },
          function (response) {
              alert('e ' + response[0].email);                  
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** *force* the user to give you his/her original e-mail address. And I can't see the problem here, whatever e-mail you want to send to the user...Facebook will forward it for you!

Comment: Some of my other apps that are not using the new Auth Dialog also ask for the users emails and recieve the original email, so the problem is with the new Auth Dialog, how do I solve this?

Comment: Well, the dialog will show the original email and the user can *change* it and choose to share a proxied email instead. Funny thing is that my test app (that uses the new dialog) only shares the default email with no option to change it!